# server error while defing foreign key

Tags: sql

```
> i am getting following error in sql
> server express while defining foreign
> key could any body resolve my problem
> 
> > 'tbl_branch' table saved successfully
> > 'tbl_students' table
> > - Unable to create relationship 'FK_tbl_students_tbl_branch'.  
> > Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
> > 'FK_tbl_students_tbl_branch' on table
> > 'tbl_students' may cause cycles or
> > multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
> > DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
> > ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
> > constraints. Could not create
> > constraint. See previous errors.
> > 
> > > Blockquote
```

Comment: Show us the foreign keys you have on all the involved tables and the one you are trying to create.

Comment: A diagram of the database tables would be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is warning that you have a "circular reference" with your foreign keys; i.e. tbl_branch has a foreign key that points to tbl_students and tbl_students has one that points to tbl_branch.

Specifically the problem is that you have cascading deletes or updates switched on. This means when you delete a row in tbl_branch, it'll try to delete the associated record in tbl_students, which will try to delete the associated record in tbl_branch, etc. In other words you may cause cylclical cascading deletions.

Either switch off cascading deletes/updates, or remove the "circular" foreign keys.

Comment: branch has a foreign key course_id ....
can u tell me what is circular reference and how to resolve it...

Comment: do these two tables both have a foreign key pointing to the other table?

Comment: A circular reference in its simplest form is when you have an FK from table A to table B and another from table B to table A. You could also have A->B->C->A, etc.  It's a problem because if you have cascading updates for example, the server can get caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: branch table has a foreign key course_id and i am trying to make branch table's branch_id as foreign key for student table .....

basically i have structure like this ..i have tables college, course, branch, student.. i am making college_id a foreign key in course table  and course_id a foreign key in branch table and in student table college_id and branch_id and course_id all three as foreign key ...but nun it works on except college_id when i define

Comment: both course_id and branch_id as foreign key in student table it throws the same error mentioned in the above comment so if i remove on delete cascade and onupdate cascade then it works ..plesase suggest me what to do..

Comment: Rob Levine..no i dont have any relation ship like A->B->A

Comment: Then perhaps, indirectly, (as Tom H suggests) you have an A->B->C->A. That does seem to be what the database is warning you about.